# How do I specify a bucket name using an s3 connection in Airflow?

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, airflow-2.x

We have an s3 bucket that Airflow uses as the source of all of our DAG data pipelines. We have a bucket for dev, test and production. Let's say the bucket in dev is called `dev-data-bucket`, in test it's called `test-data-bucket` etc.

I don't want to manually specify the bucket name in our DAG code because this code gets migrated between environments. If I manually specify the `dev-data-bucket` in our dev environment and this DAG code goes to our test environment, the bucket name would need to  change to `test-data-bucket` and `prod-data-bucket` for prod.

I understand that the usual way to do this would be to create an Airflow connection in each environment which has the same name like `data-bucket`. However, I don't know where to specify the bucket name in the connection screen for airflow like I would for a database connection?

How do I create an Airflow s3 connection with the same name in each environment but which specifies a different bucket name for each environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to specify the bucket name in the `Schema` field in the Airflow connection screen. This is what the connection screen would look like in dev:

[image]

Then, when you use one of the provided s3 operators in airflow you don't need to specify a bucket name because the s3 hook in Airflow is setup to fetch the bucket name from the connection if you haven't specified one.